# Prove recurrence relation using mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

solve recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n–1} + 12 a_{n–2}$,
where $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 11$ and Verify, using Principle of Mathematical
Induction, that $a_n = (-1)(-3)^n + (2)(4^n)$.

ans: i have done so far.. 
put $a_n=b_n$
$a_n-a_{n-1}-12a_{n-2}=0$
$b_n-b_{n-2}-12a_{n-2}=0$
$b^2-b-12=0$, $b=-3,4$

Comment: Why are you putting $a_n = b_n$?  What purpose does having two notation for the same terms mean?

Comment: A "classic" induction proof would show it's true for initial values of n (so n = 2 here), then assuming it's true for some n, show it's also true for n + 1. I haven't followed through with the proof so it may end up not working out, but that's how I'd start here.

Comment: So then the general solution is $a_n = k_1(-3)^n + k_2(4)^n$, and use initial conditions $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 11$ to get the general $a_n = (-1)(-3)^n + (2)(4^n)$. I am assuming that you can take care of the induction

Comment: I don't know how to politely say this but everything about this is completely wrong.  $a_n \ne a^n$.  This isn't trying to solve an equation.  $a_n$ simply means that it is the nth term in a sequence of numbers.  The first, $a_0 = 1$ and the next, $a_1$ is 11, so the third is $a_2 = a_1 + 12a_0 = 11 + 12 = 23$.  And so on to get a sequence of numbers {1,11,23,a_3, a_4, .......}  You need to do a "proof by induction" to show that the $a_n$ term of these numbers is actually equal to $(-1)(-3)^n + (2)(4^n)$

Comment: Maybe you meant $a_n = b^n$ ?

Comment: @JoelCohen Perhaps she/he did but why the heck would someone want to do that and how the heck *could* someone do that?

Comment: You aren't trying to solve anything.  You are trying to determine what the formula is for {1, 11, 23, 23+12*11, ....}.  You are given that the formula will be $a_n$ (the n plus oneth term) is $a_n = (-1)(-3)^n + (2)(4^n)$.  Now you have to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1} = a_n + 12a_{n-1}=$

$[(-1)(-3)^n + (2)(4^n)] + 12[(-1)(-3)^{n-1} + (2)(4^{n-1})]=$

.....

$(-1)(-3)^{n+1} + (2)(4^{n+1})$

Fill in the ...